# java webdriver bootstrap dropdown selecting div>p item

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to run some tests on this page http://www.funding-portal.eu/ncp-search/

There are 2 input boxes that use the bootstrap dropdown, which is populated with items that contain the text input.

My test inputs one letter to create a list, then stores all the titles in the returned dropdown in an array, which it will pick a random item from and put that text back into the input field.

This works fine on the second dropdown but not the first.

Also one needs to be able to click the item in the list so it opens any relevant items below. I am having real issues with the click part. Here is the code I have tried:

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("programmeFocusAreaPicker")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("programmeFocusAreaPicker")).sendKeys("a");

        dropdown = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.tt-suggestion>p"));
        count = dropdown.size();

        System.out.println("Info,Options available = "+count);
        System.out.println("Info,Start looping");

        int a = 0;
        String[] itemArray = new String[count];
        count--;
        int rand1 = rand.nextInt((count - 0) + 1) + 0;

        for (WebElement dd : dropdown) {
            itemArray[a] = dd.getText();
            a++;
        }
        System.out.println("Info,sendkeys = " + itemArray[rand1]);
        driver.findElement(By.id("programmeFocusAreaPicker")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("programmeFocusAreaPicker")).sendKeys(itemArray[rand1]);

        Actions cursor = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement item = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.tt-suggestion>p"));
        cursor.moveToElement(item);
        cursor.click(item);
```

I have previously tried to click on the first returned item without having to repeat the clear&sendKeys.

I have spent quite a lot of time searching for an answer to this so I apologise if it is seen as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using build().perform() function which are used to execute any functionality of Actions class.
  Replace your last lines in the code with these below steps.

```
    Actions cursor = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement item = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.tt-suggestion>p"));
    cursor.moveToElement(item);
    cursor.click(item).build().perform();
```

Comment: such simple mistakes. Thank you.